# Translate Sql query with subquery to CAML

Tags: sql, sharepoint, subquery, caml

I want to create a caml query from an sql query. The sql query contains a subquery from the same list.

I've tried it a thousand ways but it does not work.

The query is:

```
Select * from "list" where NameUser = (select NameUser from "list" where responsible = [Me])
```

The `Responsable` field is user type and `NameUser` field is of type `string`.

Thank you very much.

Alex.

Comment: Can you prove a sample of what the source `list` data looks like? It may also help to provide a logical description (not just SQL) of what you're intended query logic is. Since both the main & subquery are querying the same list, it's not clear why you cannot simply query for "responsible = [Me]"

Comment: This list is used to impute working hours.

Some fields are Project, Task, Responsible ...

Depending on the project in which you impute, you will have a different manager.

I want to make a view of those responsible to see those people who are in your project. But not only the line that impute to that project, but all the lines of that person, whether of his project or not.

Comment: An example:

Person C is responsible in A and in B
Person D is responsible in B

C can look at the line of B in which D is responsible.
D can look at the line of B in which C is responsible.
D can NOT look at line A because D has never been responsible for A.

I hope to explain myself well, my English is very limited.

I will try to explain it another way if it has not been clear.

Thank you very much.